# Problema Básico con una función

Tags: javascript, javascript-objeto

Estoy empezando con el Javascript y llevo toda la tarde dando vueltas a un codigo y no entiendo donde esta el problema.

El ejercicio seria puntuar unas manos de cartas. Con dos condiciones. Los palos rojos valen doble y los 1 (As) valen 20.

Total el 1 de corazones = 40 , 1 de picas = 20, etc..

EL tema es que he creado una funciona que puntual el valor de una array de objetos, y cumple las condiciones y funciona.

Luego tengo que comparar cual de las dos manos es mayor y mostrarlo, y aqui es donde me falla, por algun motivo que no entiendo no me funciona.

Seguro que lo veis en un momento, pero yo no lo veo.

Funcion que puntua.

```
function puntua(mano)
 {
        var total= 0;
        for (i=0; i<mano.length; i=i+1) {
        var valor= mano[i].v
         if (valor===1) {valor=20} 
         var color= mano[i].p
         if (color==="c" || color==="d")
          {valor=valor*2} 

         total= total + valor

 }
  return total;
}
```

Función que deberia mostrar que mano es la mayor.

```
function ganador(){
var ganador=0
if (mano1<mano2){
    console.log("mano1 vale: "+puntua(mano1))
    console.log("mano2 vale: "+puntua(mano2))
    console.log("El ganador es: mano2 con un valor: "+puntua(mano2))
}
if (mano1>mano2){
    console.log("mano1 vale: "+puntua(mano1))
    console.log("mano2 vale: "+puntua(mano2))
    console.log("El ganador es: mano1 con un valor: "+puntua(mano1))
    }
return ganador
```

Creo las manos e invoco al la funciona ganador que compara.

```
var mano1 =[{p:"d", v: 2}, {p:"t", v: 6}, {p:"d", v: 7}, {p: "d", v: 9},{p:"t", v:1}, {p:"p", v: 8}] //suman 70
        
var mano2 =[{p:"d", v:1}, {p:"t", v:3}, {p:"c", v:1}, {p:"c",v: 1},{p:"p",v: 12}] //suman 135
       
ganador(mano2,mano1);
```

El RESULTADO, que me sale por pantalla es este:

mano1 vale: 70
mano2 vale: 135

El ganador es: mano1 con un valor: 70

En algún sitio parece que me esta cruzando los valores o no se...

Agradecía la aclaración ya que no veo el problema en un código tan sencillo.

Grácias

Comment: Que significan las letras *c*, *t*, *d*, etc?

Comment: c, es palo corazon, t, treboles... etc...

Answer (score 0):

El error principal esta en

```
if (mano1>mano2)
```

Estas comparando los dos arreglos, debes comparar los totales

```
if (puntua(mano1) > puntua(mano2))
```

El codigo quedaria asi:

```js
function puntua(mano) {
  var total = 0;
  for (i = 0; i < mano.length; i = i + 1) {
    var valor = mano[i].v
    if (valor === 1) {
      valor = 20
    }
    var color = mano[i].p
    if (color === "c" || color === "d") {
      valor = valor * 2
    }
    total = total + valor
  }
  return total;
}

function ganador(mano1, mano2) {
  var ganador = 0
  if ( puntua(mano1) > puntua(mano2)) {
    console.log("mano1 vale: " + puntua(mano1))
    console.log("mano2 vale: " + puntua(mano2))
    console.log("El ganador es: mano1 con un valor: " + puntua(mano1))
  }else{
   console.log("mano1 vale: " + puntua(mano1))
    console.log("mano2 vale: " + puntua(mano2))
    console.log("El ganador es: mano2 con un valor: " + puntua(mano2))
  }
  return ganador
}


var mano1 =[{p:"d", v: 2}, {p:"t", v: 6}, {p:"d", v: 7}, {p: "d", v: 9},{p:"t", v:1}, {p:"p", v: 8}] //suman 70
        
var mano2 =[{p:"d", v:1}, {p:"t", v:3}, {p:"c", v:1}, {p:"c",v: 1},{p:"p",v: 12}] //suman 135
ganador(mano1, mano2);
```

Comment: Muchas gracias por la aclaración, me lio bastante con el paso de parametros entre funciones y muchas veces no se que esta en cada variable... por ejemplo el sentido de la variable ganador, que no le veo utilidad. Muchas gracias.

Comment: Una duda, Patxi, no te faltaría en los condicionales donde compruebas si la puntuación de una mano es menor o mayor que la otra el caso de que ambas puntuaciones fuesen iguales??????????

Comment: Sii, el caso de empate no lo había contemplado... Lo voy a mirar de poner tambien...